# Uninstall AIR Application Programmatically

Tags: command-line, air, uninstallation

Is it possible to uninstall an AIR Application programmatically (or via command line)? I know I can uninstall the AIR Runtime programmatically.

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by deleting the .app Directory of the Application to uninstall. This met my usecase, but if someone knows how to do this with windows or linux, I'm looking forward for other answers :)

Comment: That was my fallback strategy, and it worked for me too.
However, I suspect there's some application-specific state stored in the Air runtime, either in a file or a registry, that will hang around.

Answer (score 0):

Please see here for uninstalling the application (not the runtime):

[Adobe Air application (not runtime) - silently uninstall using an administrative command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19958344/adobe-air-application-silently-uninstall-using-an-administrative-command/19958345#19958345)