# Adobe Air application (not runtime) - silently uninstall using an administrative command?

Tags: air, adobe, uninstallation

The Adobe Air documentation mentions how to install silently but for uninstallation cryptically mentions an "ARH" utility and alternative (complicated) methods.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/redist/WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-8000.html#WS485a42d56cd19641-70d979a8124ef20a34b-7ffb

Answer (score 1):

The general Adobe Air application installer has an -uninstall option:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe AIR\Versions\1.0\Adobe AIR Application Installer.exe" -uninstall -silent "C:\Program Files (x86)\YOUR-APP-NAME\YOUR-APP-NAME.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
==================================================================
echo   Silent uninstall Adobe Air 
===================================================================
AdobeAIRInstaller.exe -uninstall
Echo Done
```